# Managing Flashforge Guider 3 Plus printer on Ultimaker Cura

Tags: ultimaker-cura, diy-3d-printer, flashforge

I seem to be having trouble managing the printer for slicing process in Ultimaker Cura. I use Flashforge Guider 3 Plus printer and added it to Ultimaker Cura manually (there was no Guider 3 Plus option for Flashforge printer in Cura). In the machine settings, I only set the printer dimensions and left the Printhead Settings as default. Machine settings will be attached below).

The slicing process went well. But what I found when I was going to print on my printer is as follows
[image: -]

Does anyone have any idea what's going on? And how is this problem solved?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it's due to your G-code, it doesn't look like you modified that either. The start and end G-code for the Flashforge printers can be grabbed from the G-code file, just open it up using notepad.

I have a Flashforge Guider 3 Ultra, but haven't tested it with Cura yet. Found your article while doing research, it looks like most people just bear with their proprietary software "Flashprint". Having found some issues with it myself, I'll be testing how well Cura works in the next few days.

Answer (score 0):

According to their own website (the FAQ), you [can ask](https://www.flashforge.com/faq-detail/use-slicers-with-Flashforge-3d-printers#:%7E:text=FAQ-,Can%20I%20use%20other%20slicers%20with%20Flashforge%203d%20printers%2C%20say,Slicer%2C%20Simplify3D%2C%20etc.%3F&text=Yes%2C%20you%20can.,parameter%20setting%20in%20those%20slicers.) for the settings.

> **Can I use other slicers with Flashforge 3d printers, say Cura, Prusa Slicer, Simplify3D, etc.?**
>
> *Yes, you can. Except for Flashforge Official slicer, Flashforge 3D printer is also compatible with other slicers. But you need to adjust some parameter setting in those slicers. Contact our support team for help.*